# Is the resulting language regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language

If $L$ is a regular language then is $L'=\{w \mid wx \in L \text{ for some string }x\}$ regular?

First step is understand $L'$. So it is a subset of $L$ that contains strings with a certain prefix?

Comment: No. It's the set of all prefixes of strings in $L$.

Comment: @BrianO could you elaborate what you mean by prefixes? So if $L=\{000, 101\}$ then $L'=\{0, 00, 1, 10\}$?

Comment: @Celeritas, technically $L'$ should include $000$ and $101$ too, they're prefixes with $x$ the suffix being $\epsilon$.

Comment: $L'$ contains all prefixes. If $L = 000 + 101$, then $L'$ contains $0,00, 1, 10$ but also $000$ and $101$, as well as $\varepsilon$. You used the word "prefix" first :) I assumed you knew what it meant. $u$ is a prefix of $y$ if $y = uv$ for some string $v$, which might be the empty string. So both $\varepsilon$ and $y$ are prefixes of $y$. If $\lvert y\rvert = n$ then $y$ has $n+1$ prefixes.

Comment: Hint: The easiest way to prove this, I think, is by transforming an FA $M$ that accepts $L$ into an NFA $M'$ that accepts $L'$. You don't have to change much about $M$ to get $M'$.

Comment: Does the hint help?

Comment: @BrianO yes, thank you very much